# SQL: Combine result sets using common value?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In MS Access 2010 I've got (a) multiple tables with names (primary key) and ID numbers; and (b) a lookup table with all possible variations of names (primary key), as well as a last name for each. e.g.

```
tableA
name         ID
"Jones, B"   1
"Smith, A"   2

tableB
name         ID
"Jones"      4
"Smith, Abe" 5

lookupTable
name         Lastname
"Smith, A"   "Smith"
"Smith, Abe" "Smith"
```

What I want to end up with is a query that returns the IDs for each distinct value in lookupTable.Lastname, e.g.

```
Lastname    tableA.ID    tableB.ID
"Smith"     2            5
```

I can't wrap my head around how to do this. So far I have something like:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(lookupTable LEFT JOIN tableA ON lookupTable.name = tableA.name) 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON lookupTable.name = tableB.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this quick hint helps. 
It's seems like you are in the right direction. I would think the same. 
You may want to add to what you have 
      SELECT * FROM 
      (lookupTable LEFT JOIN tableA ON lookupTable.name = tableA.name) 
      LEFT JOIN tableB ON lookupTable.name = tableB.name

Something like 
     SELECT DISTINCT Statement
As shown in this page.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

I hope this helps.

Thank you,